# RabbitMQ not showing message rates

Tags: python, python-2.7, rabbitmq, pika

I'm a newbie to Rabbit MQ so please be gentle.

My problem is that I'm trying to monitor the throughput of messages for a test scenario. I've got a backlog queue that with tasks to process in worker tasks. Each worker is inserting the results into a couchbase database.

Based on the couchbase ops per second (between 20 and 200), I can see how many tasks are completed, but the management console for Rabbit MQ shows 0.0. What am I doing wrong? what is the best alternative way to get this estimate?

RabbitMQ is currently running on localhost, the scripts used to enqueue and dequeue items are written in Python 2.7 using Pika to interact with RabbitMQ 3.2.1

[image: Screenshot with waiting messages and message rates in RabbitMQ]
[image: Screenshot with messages arriving in Couchbase]

Comment: Any progress? I have the same issue, coming through node-amqp and the rabbitmq stomp/websocket broker.

Comment: I know this is old, but I'm experiencing the same issue now with Pika on python 2.7 with rabbit 3.3.5